# delphi xe2 stringgrid with comments

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tstringgrid

Can anyone recommend a good stringgrid like component for Delphi that handles comments on each cell similar to Microsoft Excel? I am searching the web but haven't found much yet and would appreciate input if someone here has used something similar

Updated with images:
Cell 1A has a comment, as indicated by red triangle

[image: cell with a comment]

A mouseover reveals the comment on the cell

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can add a picture to make this clearer? I am not sure what "similar to excel" means here.

Comment: +1 for adding a picture, that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the existing `TStringGrid` component.  Use its `Objects` property to store custom per-cell data, such as a comment `String`, and then you can use the `THintWindow` class to display that comment to the user when needed.

Comment: That sounds promising. I was already placing values in my grid using StringGrid.Cells[x,y] := value. Is there a way to store a comment alongside that value? Or would I need another grid? Also what would be a good way in this case to indicate to the user that there is a comment in on the cell? (Excel uses the red triangle in the corner)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `Objects` property, not the `Cells` property. I have updated my answer. As for displaying an indicator to the user, I would owner-draw the cells using the `OnDrawCell` event. Whenever a comment has been stored in the `Objects` property, you can draw whatever kind of indicator you want in the cell.